# call anonymous function composable in other component vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I´m trying to call anonymous function defined in constant variable in my composable, and i need to call it in my component parent, that this anonimous function will fill my table with any data. I´m trying this:

my composable:

```
export default function useNcalls(){
    let calls = ref([])
    let param_search = ref([])
    let pagination = ref([])

    const getCall = async (param_search) => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/callApi', {param_search: {'param_search': param_search} }) 
        console.log("llego")
        calls.value = response.data.data
    } 
    const deleteCall = (id) => axios.post(`/api/callApi/${id}`, {_method: 'delete'}).then(res => {
        confirm("¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el registro?") 
        location.reload();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });  
    
    const queryForKeywords = async (event) => {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/callApi/show', { params: { 'searchParams': event } }) 
        calls.value = response.data.data
    };

    const getResults = async (page) => {
        const response = axios.get('api/callApi?page=' + page)
        calls.value = response.data
    };

    const getItems = async (page) => {
        axios.get('/api/callApi?page='+page)
            .then(response => {
                calls.value = response.data.data;
                pagination.value = response.data.meta;
            });
    };

    return{
        calls,
        getCall,
        deleteCall,
        queryForKeywords,
        getResults,
        getItems
    } 
}
```

i have one component that create table and any methods that use this composable:

```
<script>
    import nUseCalls from "../../composables/ncalls"
    import { onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue'
    
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',
        data(){
            return{
                items: [],
                    pagination: {
                        current_page: 1,
                    },
            }
        },
        
        setup(props, context) {
            const { calls, getCall, deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = nUseCalls()
            

            function remove(id) {
                deleteDates(id)
            }
            
            function searchId(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchName(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('name_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchPhone(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('phone_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function edit(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/calls/'+action+"/edit";
            }


            function getPage(page){
                getItems(page);
            }

            context.expose({ getCall })

            return { 
                calls,
                remove,
                searchId,
                searchName,
                searchPhone,
                edit,
                getResults,
                getPage,
                getCall
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

and i have my component parent, that include before component that i expose:

```
<script>

    import { onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue';
    import useNassignedCall from "../composables/ncalls"
    import asignedCalls from './roomBooss/asignedCalls';
    import nAsignedCalls from './roomBooss/nasignedCalls';


    export default defineComponent({
        components: {asignedCalls, nAsignedCalls},
        data(){
            return{
                items: [],
                    pagination: {
                        current_page: 1,
                    },
            }
        },
        
        setup(props, context) {
            var param_search = "";
            const { calls, getCall, deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNassignedCall()
            

            function remove(id) {
                deleteCalls(id)
            }
            
            function searchId(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchName(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('name_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchPhone(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('phone_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function edit(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/telemarketing/call/'+action+"/edit";
            }

            function show(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/telemarketing/call/'+action;
            }

            function getPage(page){
                getItems(page);
            }

            function searchRegisters(){
                var address = "";
                var city = "";
                var cp = "";

                address = document.getElementById("address").value
                if( address != "" ) {
                    param_search = "address";
                }

                city = document.getElementById("city").value
                if( city != "" ) {
                    param_search = "city";
                }

                cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
                if( cp != "" ) {
                    param_search = "cp";
                }

                context.expose({ getCall })
            }

            return { 
                calls,
                remove,
                searchId,
                searchName,
                searchPhone,
                edit,
                show,
                getResults,
                getPage,
                getCall,
                searchRegisters
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

In my function searchRegisters() i need call getCall sending param_search that this anonymous function call laravel API to get all my data.

always return en my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _roomBooss_nasignedCalls__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.getCall is not a function
    at Proxy.searchRegisters (app.js:20026:114)
    at onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (app.js:21762:21)
    at callWithErrorHandling (app.js:7336:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (app.js:7345:21)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (app.js:15616:86)
```

or `app.js:7203 [Vue warn]: expose() should be called only once per setup().`

thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no getCall in searchRegisters. The error suggests that you tried to do something like nasignedCall.getCall(), this is not how it works. nasignedCall is component i.e. component options. You need to a ref of component instance

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your response and sorry for my bad question... How i can solve my problem? define a ref¿?

Comment: Specifically, template ref https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html . There should be childRef.value.getCall() in searchRegisters, no expose() there.  If this still doesn't work, please, update the question with relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve my question with this code:

first in my component:

call to my function ref

```
getCall(toRef(param_search,'param_search'))
```

in my composable add onMounted and watch

```
onMounted(() => {
        if (param_search) {
            getCall(param_search)
        }
    })
    watch(
        () => param_search,
            (val) => {
                if (val) {
                loading.value = true
                getCall(val)
            }
        },
    )
```

with this, i can access to my function

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is to use the composable in your child component, and then use template refs to pass the result around. IMO it does not make sense to use a composable that way, and I would try to avoid using template refs in general.

Looking at your code, the issue seems to be that the functions from the composable change the `calls` ref, and you have to make sure that both parent and child component use functions that alter the same `calls` ref. A way to do this is to use provide/inject inside the composable. Then you can setup the provide in the parent component, and inject the ref into any component that needs it.

You code doesn't even need to change much. This is what the composable could look like:

```
import { provide, inject } from 'vue'

const callsSymbol = Symbol.for('calls-api-variable') // <---- create a symbol for the injection

export function createCallsApi(){
  const calls = ref([])
  const pagination = ref([])

  const getCall = async (param_search) => {...} 
  const deleteCall = (id) => ...
  const queryForKeywords = async (event) => {...};
  const getResults = async (page) => {...};
  const getItems = async (page) => {...};

  const callsApi = {
    calls,
    getCall,
    deleteCall,
    queryForKeywords,
    getResults,
    getItems
  } 

  provide(callsSymbol, callsApi) // <----- add a provide
  return callsApi
}

export function useCallsApi(){ // <---- composable to resolve the inject
  const callsApi = inject(callsSymbol)
  if (!callsApi) throw new Error('Failed to inject callsApi. Did you call createCallsApi() in a parent component?')
  return callsApi
}
```

With that, in your parent, you do

```
const { calls, getCall,...} = createCallsApi()
```

and in the child:

```
const { calls, getCall,...} = useCallsApi()
```

And that's all, no fumbling around with template refs.

Does that work for you, does it make sense?

Comment: thanks for your response and your help. I think that this can help me. But when i updated my code with all your response, en console when i clicked my button to send data to composable, return: Uncaught ReferenceError: provide is not defined

Comment: Oh, you need to import provide and inject from vue. I have added the statement to the answer

Comment: thanks, also if i remove default in export, return WARNING in ./resources/js/components/formTelemarketing.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/components/formTelemarketing.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 20:26-40
export 'default' (imported as 'createCallsApi') was not found in '../composables/ncalls' (possible exports: createCallsApi, useCallsApi)

Comment: use `import { createCallsApi } from '../composables/ncalls'`

Comment: now i apply your response, but form not show nothing, no action

Comment: now to use import return ERROR in ./resources/js/composables/ncalls.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\gds_nuevo\resources\js\composables\ncalls.js: Identifier 'createCallsApi' has already been declared. (8:16)

Comment: if it's any use i need call this composable in action button that call to function searchRegisters() in my component form

Comment: Looks like you declared `createCallsApi` twice. You IDE should mark that as an error too

Comment: only have createCallsApi one twice, in export function, and import... how said me

Comment: now i can to do that your response run for me. But i don´t know how i can to do, for send parameter to my anonymous function getCall and this return my data... when i clicked my button in form. Thanks for help